# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on the Asus transformer?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am planning to buy a netvertible (tablet netbook hybrid) and install Ubuntu 11.04 on it, probably as a dual boot with the shipped OS.

The Asus transformer which was just released looks really nice. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on it? If so, what works (out of the box or through work-arounds), what doesn't?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Native Ubuntu:**

If native ubuntu works on your Asus Transformer depends on your model, as the transformer needs to be rootable with the nflash method. To find out check your serial number (next to the cable port)

- If your serial number B4O-B6O, it will work
- If your serial number is B70 it might work
- If your serial number is B8O or higher it will not work (you can root your TF101 using Razorclaw though)

full details for installation can be found at the [xda wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ASUS_Eee_Pad_Transformer/How_to_install_Ubuntu)

**VNC:**

This should work on all models, details for installation can be found in this [forum thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1145601)

Answer (score 4):

personally, i havent tried it yet, but people at modaco ( android based forum ) discuss about it, you can check it

http://android.modaco.com/content/asus-eee-pad-transformer-transformer-modaco-com/337267/some-kind-of-linux-ubuntu-on-the-transformer/#entry1670772

and

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=13290506

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer for now as no one seems to have managed to get it running yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu on Transformer is here.**

As reported by @Uli, thanks to **XDA dev** now is possible to running Ubuntu native on Asus eee pad transformer.

[Follow this step by step guide to install Ubuntu](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1163082) on micro sd card of your Transformer and boot it.

The guide is for windows, but in **Ubuntu** (and GNU/Linux in general) is more easy.
*Simply don't install driver and use flash.sh* (and restore.sh to restore boot.img to run Android) instead of flash.bat.

PS. flash.sh and bootloader related files are indicated on the official *[DEV] Native Ubuntu !!* thread indicated by @Uli).

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu as mentioned above.

1) Flash.sh

```
# ./flash.sh
Nvflash started
rcm version 0X20001
System Information:
   chip name: t20
   chip id: 0x20 major: 1 minor: 3
   chip sku: 0x8
   chip uid: 0x033c20c143608197
   macrovision: disabled
   hdcp: enabled
   sbk burned: true
   dk burned: true
   boot device: emmc
   operating mode: 4
   device config strap: 2
   device config fuse: 0
   sdram config strap: 0

sending file: transformer.bct
- 4080/4080 bytes sent
transformer.bct sent successfully
odm data: 0x300d8011
downloading bootloader -- load address: 0x108000 entry point: 0x108000
sending file: bootloader.bin
| 943193/943193 bytes sent
bootloader.bin sent successfully
waiting for bootloader to initialize
bootloader downloaded successfully
Nvflash started
[resume mode]
sending file: boot-new.img
/ 6242304/6242304 bytes sent
boot-new.img sent successfully
WHOO HOO! UBUNTU Installed!
```

2) Restore.sh

```
# ./restore.sh 
Nvflash started
rcm version 0X20001
System Information:
   chip name: t20
   chip id: 0x20 major: 1 minor: 3
   chip sku: 0x8
   chip uid: 0x033c20c143608197
   macrovision: disabled
   hdcp: enabled
   sbk burned: true
   dk burned: true
   boot device: emmc
   operating mode: 4
   device config strap: 2
   device config fuse: 0
   sdram config strap: 0

sending file: transformer.bct
- 4080/4080 bytes sent
transformer.bct sent successfully
odm data: 0x300d8011
downloading bootloader -- load address: 0x108000 entry point: 0x108000
sending file: bootloader.bin
| 943193/943193 bytes sent
bootloader.bin sent successfully
waiting for bootloader to initialize
bootloader downloaded successfully
Nvflash started
[resume mode]
sending file: boot.img
- 4200448/4200448 bytes sent
boot.img sent successfully
Android RESTORED!
```

Comment: You didn't mention any way to download above.